# How to find number of days since beginning of fiscal month?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, datetime, date

This relates to my question [How to find XXth day of previous month in SQL server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74975/how-to-find-xxth-day-of-previous-month-in-sql-server)

The fiscal month starts on 26th of each month.

I need to find out from any date:

- The date of the start of the fiscal month (Start_Of_Fiscal_Month)
- The number of days into the fiscal month (Day_Of_Fiscal_Month)

For example:

```
CurrentDate - '2014-04-26'

Start_Of_Fiscal_Month = 2014-04-26
Day_Of_Fiscal_Month = 1
```

---

```
CurrentDate - '2014-05-02'

Start_Of_Month = 2014-04-26
Day_Of_Fiscal_Month = 7
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do it:

```
DECLARE @d DATE = '20140502', @dm TINYINT = 26;
DECLARE @Start_Of_Fiscal_Month DATE

SET @Start_Of_Fiscal_Month = DATEADD(DAY, @dm-1, DATEADD(MONTH, -1 + DATEPART(dd, @d)/26, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(@d), @d)));
SELECT @Start_Of_Fiscal_Month
SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, @Start_Of_Fiscal_Month, @d) + 1
```

Comment: The formula can be further simplified to this: `SET @Start_Of_Fiscal_Month = DATEADD(DAY, @dm-DAY(@d), DATEADD(MONTH, -1 + DATEPART(dd, @d)/26, @d));`